# Removing appended "break" instruction in inline mips assembly

Tags: rust, mips, inline-assembly

I have the following (simplified) function using inline assembly, targeting mips:

```rust
#[naked]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn test() {
    asm!(
        ".set noreorder",
        "jr $ra",
        "li $v0, 0x123",
        options(noreturn),
    )
}
```

I expected this to compile into just the 2 specified instructions (in release mode), as it's a naked function, but a `break` instruction gets appended at the end:

```
00000000 <test>:
   0:   03e00008        jr      ra
   4:   24020123        li      v0,291
   8:   0000000d        break
```

I assume this is a countermeasure against undefined behavior by either rustc or llvm, but I need to product the exact assembly I specify in the function.

**Is there any way to prevent either rustc, llvm or the assembler from generating this extra instruction generally?**

I tested it on existing targets such as `mipsel-unknown-none` and it also produced a `break` instruction, but I am compiling on the following custom target, if it matters:

```json
{
    "arch": "mips",
    "cpu": "mips1",
    "data-layout": "e-m:m-p:32:32-i8:8:32-i16:16:32-i32:32-n32-S32",
    "emit-debug-gdb-scripts": false,
    "executables": false,
    "features": "+mips32,+soft-float,+noabicalls",
    "linker": "rust-lld",
    "linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
    "llvm-target": "mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu",
    "relocation-model": "static",
    "target-pointer-width": "32",
    "panic-strategy": "abort",
    "singlethread": true,
    "dynamic-linking": false,
    "function-sections": true
}
```

I'm also using a `#![no_std]` and `#![no_core]` `staticlib` crate with the required lang items implemented and simply compiling using `cargo build --release --target=my-target.json`

Edit: After Peter Cordes's suggestion, I tried the same in C with

```c
__attribute__((naked)) void test() {
    __asm__(
        ".set noreorder\n"
        "jr $ra\n"
        "li $v0, 0x123\n"
    );
}
```

Compiled using

```
clang -O3 test.c -c -o test.o -target mips-unknown-none
```

And the result is

```
00000000 <test>:
   0:   03e00008    jr  ra
   4:   24020123    li  v0,291
```

Without a `break`, so it seems it was included by the rust compiler.

Comment: If you remove the noreturn, does it put the normal function return?  Given that it's a naked function, I'm unsure.  Seems like something to try, anyway.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Unfortunately, if I remove it, I get a warning (that says it will be promoted to an error soon) saying that asm in naked functions must have `noreturn`.

Comment: I wonder if clang does this with C inline asm for MIPS?

Comment: @PeterCordes It actually doesn't (see the question edit), so it seems it's the rust compiler adding it in at some point, I'll go check the llvm ir emitted to see if it's there.

Comment: Actually, weirdly enough if I emit the llvm-ir from rust, pass it to llvm with `llc test.ir -o test.s -mtriple=mips-unknown-none` and then assemble it with `mips-unknown-gnu-as test.s -o test.o` it also doesn't have the break instruction, I assume then, it's some flag rustc is passing to llvm that causes this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Do one of:

- Add `"trap_unreachable": false` to your target.json
- Build with `RUSTFLAGS=-Ztrap-unreachable=no`. (nightly-only though)

Unfortunately it's not very well documented. Further reading: [PR where the trap instruction generation was added](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/45920) [PR where trap-unreachable=no was added](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/79367)

Comment: In the first it should be `trap-unreachable` (with a hyphen instead of underscore), but aside from that, this work perfectly! Thanks for tracking down the implementation and flag PRs

Comment: Weird that this is needed in a `naked` function at all; that's a special case where execution should never fall out the bottom of the asm statement.